# Itunes Podcast Feed: Itunes says it can't verify the identity of the server

Tags: podcast

I have created an iTunes RSS feed for my video podcast:
http://designmind.info/feeds/itunes.xml

For the first few weeks, it worked fine. But lately, iTunes has started giving this error message:

iTunes can’t verify the identity of the server “www.designmind.info”.
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.designmind.info”, which could put your confidential information at risk. Would you like to connect to the server anyway?

How can I fix this. It is not SSL hosting, so I am not sure why it needs a certificate.

Comment: You might want to try cleaning up your feed.  See [Feed Validation](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) and your [result](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdesignmind.info%2Ffeeds%2Fitunes.xml).  I offer this so we can rule out syntax as a cause.

Comment: @ECarterYoung Thanks for your help. I have validated my feed, but the problem still remains. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: See Here:  Is the [Server Time Correct](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21787886)?

Comment: @ECarterYoung Thanks for your help. the time on my Mac is correct. Can webhosting have a server time?

Comment: Yes, Check the Timezone in your Hosting Control Panel